# When you "npm start" for react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When you do

```
npm start
```

it runs in localhost:3000.
Can I make it run at "localhost:3000/home" at first? rather than localhost:3000?

Answer (score 2):

npm start is a command which is you run to start the front reactJs development server it runs on the port 3000 or any other you wish.

As above mentioned in question localhost:3000/home you have to route in reactJs
Example:

`<Route exact path="/home" component={HomeScreen}/>`

If you route like this in your component, in first render it will show the Home screen